# How can I print total clicked number of checkboxes within a function in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a function inside a class and with this
function, I want to calculate how many checkboxes clicked.

```py
# This function assesses number of clicked items in my class's list
    def badper(self):
        window=Tk()
        window.config(bg='lightgreen')
        # total = 0
        def show(self):
            new_label = Label(window, text=var.get()).pack()
        var=IntVar()
        def create_check_button(self,i):
            var = IntVar()
            c=Checkbutton(window,text=self.badcharacter[i],variable=var)
            c.pack()
            # if c == 1:
            #     global total
            #     total += 1
        # This loop creates checkboxes in the equivalent of number items of my list
        for i in range(6):
            create_check_button(self,i)

        # This button should show how many items clicked so far
        my_button=Button(window,text="show", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"),command=show(self)).pack()
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: I know but this is very similar case with the previous one.

Comment: @ugurçapan: I notice that you create a `var` for each of the checkbuttons, but nowhere do you save a list of either the checkbuttons _or_ their variables. I suggest making a list of the checkbuttons' variables, and then using that list later in the program to get how many checkbuttons were clicked. And if you have two similar (but different) questions, please put them in two _seperate_ questions. Questions shouldn't have multiple questions inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code achieves the correct outcome with the total number of set `Checkbuttons` displayed.

Remarks in code explain the problems in this simplified snippet.

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.config(bg='lightgreen')

store_var = []

def show():
    total = 0
    # This is one way to display results
    for a in store_var:
        if a.get():
            total = total + 1
    my_label["text"] = f"Total = {total}"

def create_check_button(i):
    var = tk.IntVar()
    # no information on badcharacter list supplied
    c = tk.Checkbutton(
        window, text = i, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable = var)
    c.pack()
    # Save each IntVar in list for use by function show()
    store_var.append(var)

for i in range(6):
    create_check_button(i)

# my_label is referenced in function show() so define my_label separately from pack
my_label = tk.Label(window, text = "Output")
my_label.pack()

# Button is not referenced anywhere so combining declaration and pack management is OK
tk.Button( window, text = "show", font = "Arial 12 bold", command = show).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you but my problem is still continue the "store_var" variable is  displaying always 0  in my every try.

Comment: Stor_var is not a variable, it is a list of `IntVar` objects. The code I supplied works on Windows 10.

Comment: I uploaded the pic the result

Comment: If you run my code it will produce a vertical column of `Checkbutton` objects with a large font button beneath. The total number is displayed above the button as a single value. You need to copy and paste my answer without any change and run it.

Comment: I run your code but the total number still shows "0" regarless of clicked.

Comment: The problem is  "var" variable if I use it inside of the loop it works but shows all elements as one value which is 000000 , if I discard it from from the loop and put it outside of the loop program does not put the checkboxes inside of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Here the picture about my project
[I use stepI button in order to display checkbotton window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5rg5.png)

[Thank you derek I am appreciated but when I clicked the show button The result shows "0"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhvMN.png)

> I used the above answer in the program I saw that I could not change the result the `total` remained the same(0).  So I tried different approach but this time **I could not run checkbutton properly.** The `store_var` displays either "000000" or "111111" (these numbers 0,1 related with item number  in my list(i))

```
def badper(self):
    window=tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("300x300")
    window.config(bg='lightgreen')

    store_var= []

    def show():

        total = 0
        # This is one way to display results
        for a in store_var:
            if a.get():
                total = total + 1
        my_label["text"] = f"Total = {total}"

    def create_check_button(i):
        var = tk.IntVar()
        # for i in self.badcharacter:

        c = tk.Checkbutton(window, text=i,onvalue=1,offvalue=0,variable=var)
        c.pack()
            # Save each IntVar in list for use by function show()
        store_var.append(var)




    for i in self.badcharacter:
        create_check_button(i)

    # my_label is referenced in function show() so define my_label separately from pack
    my_label = tk.Label(window, text="Output")
    my_label.pack()
    result = tk.Button(window,text="show",font=("Arial",12,"bold"),command=show).pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem is  "var" variable if I use it inside of the loop it works but shows all elements as one value which is 000000 , if I discard it from from the loop and put it outside of the loop program does not put the checkboxes inside  the window.

Comment: `store_var.append(var.get())` is saving the **value** of var not var itself. This means any changes to checkbuttons will not be recorded. You need to change it back to `store_var.append(var)` so each `IntVar` is available when you call `show()`. Also you've removed the routine that calculates total.

Comment: I updated above my answer so you will see that the total remains the same. still the store_var has no element and value is 0

Answer (score 0):

> I found it! Finally :)
> Thank you Derek you helped me a lot finding this solution.
> the link s question answer helped me : [How to get the value of Checkbox in Python when working with different functions in a same class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56088623/15174751)

**I replaced Tk() with Toplevel() function and it worked :)**

```
def badper(self):
    window=tk.Toplevel()
    window.geometry("300x300")
    window.config(bg='lightgreen')

    store_var= []

    def show():

        total = 0
        # This is one way to display results
        for a in store_var:
            if a.get():
                total = total + 1
        my_label["text"] = f"Total = {total}"

    def create_check_button(i):
        var = tk.IntVar()
        # for i in self.badcharacter:

        c = tk.Checkbutton(window, text=i,onvalue=1,offvalue=0,variable=var)
        c.pack()
            # Save each IntVar in list for use by function show()
        store_var.append(var)




    for i in self.badcharacter:
        create_check_button(i)

    # my_label is referenced in function show() so define my_label separately from pack
    my_label = tk.Label(window, text="Output")
    my_label.pack()
    result = tk.Button(window,text="show",font=("Arial",12,"bold"),command=show).pack()
    window.mainloop()
```